# data() command in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I have just realized that the  `data()` command does not work in RStudio.
It normally gives you a list of all datasets that are available to you (depending on which packages you are using).

Does anyone know of a workaround?

A very bad workaround it this:

```
x <- edit(data())
```

at least it does give you the list after several path and other listings.

Comment: It works on mine (I have a bit older version 0.95.261 & Win 7). It opens a new tab to script editor window.

Comment: I updated to newest version on Win 7 and it still works. Have you checked new tabs in Rstudio? Maybe you have not specified "Source" to one of the panels in "Options" => "Pane Layout"?

Comment: When you say doesn't work, do you mean 'does nothing' or 'does something, but not what I'd expect'?

Comment: Works for me on W7, 0.97.168.

Comment: @sebastian-c in my Ubuntu Linux version nothing happens at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to only be a problem in the Linux version of RStudio!

Answer (score 1):

As many have pointed out, `data()` works just fine in RStudio.  Since it generates a standalone window, it is true that the output is not by default,an RStudio window, but all you have to do is select RStudio from that Windows "pick the default application" dialog window, and you're all set.
(vsn 97.245 w/ R2.15.2 and Win7)

Comment: Ok, it probably doesn't work because I'm using the Linux version of R Studio!